# ld: 14 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 in iOS PayPal sdk integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, xcode6.4, ios8.4

I am new in iOS, so please help ** i already add all framework  and sdk of paypal. i  also checked duplication of linkes** how to solve this error.
thanks in advance

### Ld /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DreamPartner normal x86_64

```
cd "/Users/alivenetsolution/Desktop/@16 july/DreamPartner"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.4
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -L/Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/alivenetsolution/Desktop/@16\ july/DreamPartner/DreamPartner/ThirdParty/PayPalMobile -F/Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/alivenetsolution/Downloads/StripeiOS-WithoutApplePay -filelist /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DreamPartner.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lc++ -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.4 -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/DreamPartner.app.xcent -framework MessageUI -lPayPalMobile -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreMedia -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework OpenGLES -lxml2 -framework PassKit -framework CoreText -framework MapKit -framework CoreLocation -framework Stripe -framework Security -framework UIKit -framework Social -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -framework AddressBook -framework Accounts -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DreamPartner_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DreamPartner
```

duplicate symbol _kPayPalOAuth2ScopeFuturePayments in:
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PackageViewController.o
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _kPayPalOAuth2ScopeProfile in:
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PackageViewController.o
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _kPayPalOAuth2ScopeOpenId in:
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PackageViewController.o
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _kPayPalOAuth2ScopePayPalAttributes in:
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PackageViewController.o
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _kPayPalOAuth2ScopeEmail in:
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PackageViewController.o
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _kPayPalOAuth2ScopeAddress in:
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PackageViewController.o
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _kPayPalOAuth2ScopePhone in:
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PackageViewController.o
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _kPayPalOAuth2ScopeAddress in:
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PackageViewController.o
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Desktop/@16 july/DreamPartner/DreamPartner/ThirdParty/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPAuthNAuthScopes.o)
duplicate symbol _kPayPalOAuth2ScopeEmail in:
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PackageViewController.o
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Desktop/@16 july/DreamPartner/DreamPartner/ThirdParty/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPAuthNAuthScopes.o)
duplicate symbol _kPayPalOAuth2ScopeFuturePayments in:
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PackageViewController.o
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Desktop/@16 july/DreamPartner/DreamPartner/ThirdParty/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPAuthNAuthScopes.o)
duplicate symbol _kPayPalOAuth2ScopeOpenId in:
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PackageViewController.o
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Desktop/@16 july/DreamPartner/DreamPartner/ThirdParty/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPAuthNAuthScopes.o)
duplicate symbol _kPayPalOAuth2ScopePayPalAttributes in:
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PackageViewController.o
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Desktop/@16 july/DreamPartner/DreamPartner/ThirdParty/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPAuthNAuthScopes.o)
duplicate symbol _kPayPalOAuth2ScopePhone in:
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PackageViewController.o
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Desktop/@16 july/DreamPartner/DreamPartner/ThirdParty/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPAuthNAuthScopes.o)
duplicate symbol _kPayPalOAuth2ScopeProfile in:
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DreamPartner-cvamdjxxcqqfirfztpoultvwmoox/Build/Intermediates/DreamPartner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DreamPartner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PackageViewController.o
    /Users/alivenetsolution/Desktop/@16 july/DreamPartner/DreamPartner/ThirdParty/PayPalMobile/libPayPalMobile.a(PPAuthNAuthScopes.o)
ld: 14 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 ##

Comment: anywhere you imported `.m` file?

Comment: libpaypalmobile.a andpackageViewController.m import in "Link Binary With Libraries" .

Comment: Remove packageViewController.m from Link Binary With Libraries.

Comment: i remove PackageViewController.m from Link Binary With Libraries after remove then add PackageViewController.m in compile source . clean and run then same error.

Comment: any update for solution ?

Comment: Hey i am facing also same issue did anyone got any solution..

Comment: I resolve this problem.Actually . kPayPalOAuth2ScopeFuturePayments have declare two .m file .please delete from .m file.